# Can I see bad sectors on an old, malfunctioning hard drive platter if I open it up? I do not care about fixing this drive. Simply curious

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

I have an old 250 GB Seagate hard drive that got really slow. I cloned it with Clonezilla on a new SSD, but I had to use the `-rescue` option since it had bad sectors. That option skips any bad sectors and just carries on cloning.

Could those bad sectors be seen on the platter? I carefully opened the drive and saw some dust particles right after I lifted the cover, but nothing else. (I really don't think I introduced that dust myself by opening it.)

For context, that drive has been running pretty much 24/7 for the last 5+ years in a factory with a lot of metallic particles in the air.

FWIW, I do not care about the original disk. This is purely for curiosity. I would have trashed this old drive anyway.

Comment: You say this: “I carefully opened the drive and saw some dust particles right after I lifted the cover, but nothing else.” And then you say this: “I really don't think I introduced that dust myself by opening it.” Are you simply curious about seeing bad sectors or do you want to fix the disk? Because at this point your assumption about the dust is 100% wrong. By opening up the drive you have exposed the platters to all kinds of dust particles and not just the ones you can see with the naked eye. The drive is dead now that you have opened it up like that. Your data clone is your only data now.

Comment: Bad sectors are invisible to the naked eye, as we can't see magnetism. Hard disks are sealed and shouldn't be opened except by a professional in a lab.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 on the other hand the OP didn't say that he wanted to continue using the drive. From what I understand he opened it for the sake of curiosity before trashing it.

Comment: @PierU Correct. Thus me saying, “Are you simply curious about seeing bad sectors or do you want to fix the disk?” If this is just curiosity at play, then fine. But there are a lot of people who come to the site and say they are “curious” when the reality is they are in over there heads and made situations worse and now come here to see if someone has a “magic spell” to fix things. Some people just don’t want to admit they made mistakes.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Yeah sorry, I did not specify that I do not care about the original disk. This is purely for curiosity. I would have trashed the old drive anyway.

Comment: @harrymc That makes sense. I read that bad sectors can be caused by dust or damage to the platter, so I was wondering whether that is observable.

Comment: @SenseiRalph Okay. Makes sense. I edited your question and title to make the curiosity aspect clear. You see, without knowing you are simply curious this question reads as a potential data recovery question. Knowing you know the drive is trashed and are just curious really changes it all. Thus I retracted my close vote and made my down vote an up vote.

Comment: In extreme cases (e.g. a head crash) there could be physical damage to the platter surface that would be visible. Modern HDDs may be less prone to head crash as they have smaller and lighter head assemblies.  Back in the 1980s a crew pushed a cabinet with an operating 14" disk drive across a concrete floor. The vibrations caused a head crash that resulted in a grooved platter where the head scrapped off the oxide.

Comment: The size of a sector on the platter is so small, it may not show without a microscope, and you may not know what to look for either, let alone that it may not be visible at all as it can be a magnetising issue. A spec of dust is likely to move away if the arm comes close to it, so that should not form any reading issues.

Comment: BTW, save the super magnets inside. The platter also can be used as a firs-surface mirror.

Comment: @LPChip Since this question has now been much better focused, I encourage you to post that comment as a fuller answer. This question is useful now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of a sector on the platter is so small, it may not show without a microscope, and you may not know what to look for either, let alone that it may not be visible at all as it can be a magnetising issue. A spec of dust is likely to move away if the arm comes close to it, so that should not form any reading issues.

Comment: "*A spec of dust is likely to move away if the arm comes close to it, so that should not form any reading issues.*" -- Totally false. A dust particle is more likely to cause a head crash. If dust was so benign as you (incorrectly) claim, then why is the HDD sealed? Why do you think HDDs are assembled in a clean room? Your false claim doesn't correlate with the facts.